# Finding a probability density function of a function of three dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have three random variables that are functions of another three random variables by pairs, say: $U=fc(X,Y)$, $V=fc(Y,Z)$ and $W=fc(X,Z)$, with $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ being independent random variables with known pfds $f_X(x)$, $f_Y(y)$ and $f_Z(z)$, respectively. The densities $f_U(u)$, $f_V(v)$ and $f_W(w)$ are also known.

I would like to know the distribution $f_K(k)$, with $K=U+V+W$.

Clearly $U$, $V$ and $W$ are correlated and thus the usual variate transformation cannot be applied.

Any hints on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I would try finding the CDF.
 $$ F_K(k) = \iiint_{\{(x,y,z): f_c(x,y)+f_c(y,z) + f_c(x,z)\le k\}} f_X(x) f_Y(y) f_Z(z)\; dx\; dy\; dz$$

Comment: Thank you Robert for your prompt reply. But, beware $K=U+V+W$, not $X+Y+Z$. Besides, your proposal, if I understand correctly, applies only for independent variates, which is not my case.

Comment: Look at the region he is integrating over

Comment: @Ram You said $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: But $U$, $V$ and $W$ are not independent (each one contains two variables that present in the other two). Doesn't that fact prevent us from applying your integral?

Comment: In other words, since any $U$, $V$ or $W$ are regular functions of the other two (e.g. $U=f(V,W)$), then there cannot be a joint density $f_{UVW}(u,v,w)$ since $(U,V,W)$ is always on the graph of the function, which has measure zero.

Or am I getting it all wrong?

Comment: Ram: Do you see a density $f_{UVW}$ in the answer? My suggestion: read slooow-ly.

Comment: Where do you see $U = f(V,W)$?

Comment: Thank you all for the clarifications, very helpful. I think I see my mistake, but now I have some problems in how to define the region of integration...

Comment: In my problem, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are $\chi_2^2$-distributed, with the same variance. Now, $U=\left(\frac{X-Y}{X+Y}\right)^2$ (and similar for $V$ and $W$).

I can prove that $U$, $V$ and $W$ are distributed $f_\Xi(\xi)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi}}$ for $\xi \in [0,1]$ and zero elsewhere, (square of a uniform) where $\Xi=U$, $V$ or $W$. Therefore $K$ must have a finite domain in $[0,3]$.

I have difficulties defining the region of integration for this case, could you help me?

Comment: Well, the region of integration is defined by the rather ugly expression $$\left(\dfrac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{y-z}{y+z}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{z-x}{z+x}\right)^2 \le k$$
I doubt that you'll get a closed form.  Numerical methods may be required.

Comment: Using numerical methods is bad news in my context. But I rephrase my last question: how can I define the limits of integration in the triple integral? I see the region, but I cannot translate it into the limits that, for instance, $x$ alone should vary, $y$ alone should vary, and $z$.

Comment: Write the inequality as 
$$ (x-y)^2 (y+z)^2 (z+x)^2 + (y-z)^2(x+y)^2(z+x)^2 + (z-x)^2(x+y)^2(y+z)^2 - k (x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2 \le 0$$
The left side is a polynomial $P(x,y,z)$, homogeneous of degree $6$, and of degree $4$ in each variable.  For each $x$ and $y$ in $[0,\infty)$, you want to integrate $z$ over the interval(s) in $[0,\infty)$ where it is nonpositive.

Comment: One interesting fact is that the coefficient of $z^4$ in $P(x,y,z)$ is $3x^2+2xy+3y^2−k(x+y)^2=P(x,y,0)/(x^2y^2)$. If $P(x,y,0)>0$, $P(x,y,z)\to+\infty$ as $z\to \infty$, so the intervals (if any) have endpoints that are solutions of $P(x,y,z)=0$. If $P(x,y,0)<0$, $P(x,y,z)\to-\infty$ as $z \to \infty$, and there will be an interval starting at $z=0$ and an interval going to $+\infty$. For example, if $k>3$ that is certainly the case (but then it is trivial that $F_K(k)=1$).

Comment: Slightly less trivial is that if $2 < k < 3$ there is a sector of $(x,y)$ values in which $P(x,y,0) < 0$.

Comment: Still working on it. It is becoming quite tedious. With the help of Mathematica, I see that there are 6 different intervals for $k\in[0,3]$ for which the integrals should be solved.

Reduce[((x - y)/(x + y))^2 + ((y - z)/(y + z))^2 + ((x - z)/(x + z))^2 <= k && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]

And still is to be understood if the integrals have an explicit solution after all.

Any other strategies you can suggest to tackle this?

Comment: As I wrote before, I doubt that there is a closed form solution.

Comment: I am still working with this integral. I was able to get a reasonably accurate solution using numerical integration, so it works. But I came back to this (old) post and there is still a notation issue that is bugging me: in your definition of the region of integration, you use the sample value of K (i.e. $f_c(x,y)+f_c(y,z)+f_c(z,x)$).Isn't this $k$? But how then to interpret $k \leq k$?